# GraphQL API Error - Unhashable type: 'StrawberryAnnotation' - Fifty One App

Tags: graphql, strawberry-graphql, fiftyone

```
File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\execute.py", line 1036, in await_result
    return build_response(await result, errors)  # type: ignore
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\execute.py", line 451, in get_results
    await gather(*(results[field] for field in awaitable_fields)),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\execute.py", line 535, in await_result
    self.handle_field_error(error, return_type)
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\execute.py", line 569, in handle_field_error
    raise error
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\graphql\execution\execute.py", line 528, in await_result
    return_type, field_nodes, info, path, await result
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\strawberry\schema\schema_converter.py", line 513, in _async_resolver
    return await await_maybe(_get_result(_source, strawberry_info, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\strawberry\utils\await_maybe.py", line 12, in await_maybe
    return await value
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fiftyone\server\paginator.py", line 107, in paginate
    return await get_items(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fiftyone\server\paginator.py", line 75, in get_items
    edges.append(Edge(node=from_db(doc), cursor=str(_id)))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fiftyone\server\paginator.py", line 105, in from_db
    return from_dict(cls, doc)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fiftyone\server\utils.py", line 108, in from_dict
    return _from_dict(data_class, data, config=_dacite_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Progr[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYhNT.png)ams\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dacite\core.py", line 72, in from_dict
    value = get_default_value_for_field(field, field_type)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dacite\dataclasses.py", line 19, in get_default_value_for_field
    elif is_optional(type_):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I encountered this error when I tried launching the FiftyOne app for computer vision tasks. I've used the same dataset and launch commands previously with no issues. I'm at total loss as I can't even diagnose the issue given this error message and my inexperience with this content. Thanks!

Comment: There's regrettably not enough here to go on.

Comment: @MichelFloyd hi, thanks for the response - I feel the same way. The only distinct things it's telling me are: "unhashable type: 'StrawberryAnnotation'" and "GraphQL API Error
    at DWr (http://localhost:5151/assets/index.432b9a97.js:863:146053)" if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have dacite>=1.8 installed. dacite>=1.6,<1.8 is required by FiftyOne

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'll try that later tonight.